# How to disable refresh for pagination in Yii2 used pjax

Tags: pagination, yii2, pjax

For pagination in Yii2 I use pjax, but for the application it is necessary to disable the page refresh. I tried to do this with the timeout parameter, but it still does an update, which affects the results of the application. How to disable refresh pjax at all or how to do ajax refresh in pagination without pjax

Comment: your question doesnot make any sense `pjax` and `ajax` are not different

Comment: I meant to implement the update of data using pagination without the pjax plugin but using jquery ajax...

Comment: that is what is confusing, well you have to bind every button on which you want to perform any action,

Comment: thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam , I should try

Comment: Can you provide some details? When does the page refresh? Did you initialize pjax, eg `$(document).pjax('a', $('#someContainer', []);`?